# My iPhone had the keypad pressed down for a long time and now i'm locked out: can the key presses be cleared?

Tags: iphone, ios

We are all pretty much obliged to keep the mobile devices handy.  I was out doing work on the house and it was in my toolbelt apparently still on and probably up close and personal with the box cutter or the tape measure.  When I click power button now there is a backlog of untold how many key presses. I've been locked out for 60 seconds, 5 minutes, now it's at Security lockout of 45 minutes.

Is there anyway to clear this out? Or do I need to wait until it simply runs out of battery power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s best to just wait out the 45 minutes.

You can bypass this, but it will require you to reset the device.  Apple has full instructions; [If you see an iPhone or iPad unavailable message or Security Lockout screen](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212951)

Keep in mind you need the following, per Apple:

> - You need to have a device that's using iOS 15.2 or iPadOS 15.2 or later.
> - Your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch needs to be connected to a cellular or Wi-Fi network.*
> - You'll need your Apple ID and password that you used to set up your device

If you absolutely must be reachable, contact your carrier to temporarily forward you number to a different one while the security lockout timer depletes .

Comment: ok tic toc tic toc ;)